Teradata Studio installation: Choosing the right zip file
I would like to install Teradata Studio on my computer. I have found the right webpage: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-studio, and (after a free registration) I can view the download links.
However, I am confused: What is the difference between TeradataStudio__win64_x86.20.00.00.03.zip and TeradataStudioJA__win64_x86.20.00.00.03.zip?
I have read the description on that page, the readme, the release definition, the installation and the user guide, and non of them mentions it.

01 - TeradataStudio__win64_x86.20.00.00.03.zip: This is the standard version of Teradata Studio. It contains the core application and is intended for general use, usually in English or other primary languages.
02 - TeradataStudioJA__win64_x86.20.00.00.03.zip: The "JA" in this filename indicates that this version includes Japanese language support. This version is for users who prefer or need the application in Japanese.

So, JA stands for Japan. I was thinking of Java something. Thanks.
